# The "select all" header checkbox that I used in Django 1.5 is missing in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, checkbox, admin

Very straightforward question. There used to be a checkbox in the header of the Django admin site, but after upgrading from Django 1.5 to 1.9 it is no longer there.

[image: Where is my select all checkbox?]

Also, I can no longer shift-select rows.

I cannot for the life of me find any configuration options around this. Hoping it is something obvious.

Comment: Quick sanity check - do you have JavaScript enabled in the browser?

Comment: Absolutely. Just confirmed for sanity in about:config, and also I'm running our React SPA.

Comment: Okay, thanks, could you please also explore the Network tab of your browser developer tools - refresh the page and see if there are any 404s?

Comment: AHHHH yes I'm getting several 404s, including a jquery.js. This is an inherited codebase ... I wonder if the previous coder did some weird customizing?

Comment: There are 6 missing SVGs. The two JS files missing are "/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js" and "/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js".

Comment: Also FYI, the cosmetic customization they did was all contained in an "admin/base_site.html" override. I have removed that override so that I am using the stock Django 1.9 admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkboxes should still be there in Django 1.9. The design for the Django admin was updated in 1.9. Your screenshot still looks like the old style, so it looks like you haven't updated the static files.

If you are in production, make sure that you have run `collectstatic` since upgrading.

```
python ./manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thank you!! The checkbox is there now, but it is behaving strangely (the header box does not toggle its visual state when clicked, and rows simply highlight and their checkboxes do not visually switch state either).  I'm thinking the previous coder may have done some customization, so I am looking into that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I found admin assets in the local static directory. When I removed them, the L&F of the admin site is completely different (much nicer!!). The select all checkboxes are still not working correctly, but I am marking yours as the solution since it lead me to my problem. Thanks again!!

Comment: **Head's up for anyone in a similar situation to mine.** The previous programmer had copied most of the Django 1.3 admin site's assets right into our static directory. Not only did I have to nuke that directory from our repository, I had to rm -rf that directory in all our staticroot directories on my dev machine and our servers to get the full functionality and L&F of the Django 1.9 site back.  I was unknowingly replacing large parts of functionality of the Django 1.9 admin site with Django 1.3 assets every time I did a collectstatic.